# Lubuntu: отключение wifi при обновлении

Tags: сеть, wifi, ubuntu

Ситуация следующая: при автообновлении машины под лубунтой выскакивает запрос рутового пароля. И в этот момент почему-то отключается `wifi`. Так всё и висит, пока пароль не введёшь. Мне не влом пароль ввести, но машина работает без монитора :) И про это узнаю только когда начинают приходить отлупы от других машин, которые туда долбятся.

Как лечить? Отключать автообновление не хочется.

Comment: не делать автообновления, я серьезно.

Comment: Там только mysql и vnc обновляются. Это плохо?

Comment: надо любить ОСь с которой работаешь, а не любишь - менять. в этом вся проблема.

Comment: @eicto, я сделаю вид что не заметил этого потока сознания...

Answer (score 1):

А если сделать автоматическое обновление через крон?!

Открываем менеджер заданий:

```
crontab -u root -e
```

Добавляем строчку:

Простое обновление пакетов:

```
0 6 * * * apt-get -y update && apt-get -y upgrade && apt-get -y clean
```

Или с поддержкой обновления до новой версии операционной системы (опасно!):

```
0 6 * * * apt-get -y update && apt-get -y upgrade && apt-get -y dist-upgrade && apt-get -y clean
```

clean очищает локальное хранилище полученных файлов пакетов. Ключ -y будет автоматически «соглашаться» на установку всех пакетов.

Теперь ежедневно в 6:00 утра сервер будет устанавливать все доступные обновления.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую. А что в этой ситуации будет с перезагрузкой?

Comment: Ну на сколько я знаю автоматически apt-get не перезагрузит машину, даже при обновлении до новой версии.